# Is there a more succinct way to use an enum especially when it only has primitive types?

Tags: rust

I'm using an enum for polymorphism in Rust. I need to have a vector that can have integers or floating point values in it:

```
enum Value {
    Float(f32),
    Int(i32),
}

let vec = Vec::<Value>::new();
vec.push(Value::Int(0));
vec.push(Value::Float(1.0));
```

Is there a more succinct way to do this, particularly when you're only using primitive types?

Comment: How much more succinct do you want it? Implicit conversion from primitive to `Value`? By the way, you don't need to specify the vector's element type here; the compiler can deduce it.

Comment: Yeah I guess this isn't any worse than C unions. I think it mostly feels strange that I'm effectively just renaming the primitive types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

There are tricks to reduce the amount of code:

1. There's no need to specify the type of the vector.
2. You could construct the vector all at once.
3. You could import the enum variants.

```
fn main() {
    use Value::*;
    let vec = vec![Int(0), Float(1.0)];
}
```

> it mostly feels strange that I'm effectively just renaming the primitive types

That's just an artifact of your program. For example, there's no real difference to the computer between your enum and this one:

```
enum MagicSpell {
    Multiplier(f32),
    NumberOfStomachs(i32),
}
```

However, the semantics (a.k.a. the names) are highly different.

Comment: Yeah, in my actual project I'm not using Float and Int, since the values I'm storing have additional semantic meaning I'm able to encode in the name, so it feels less wasteful.